# Installation Error In Cakephp

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, ubuntu-14.04

After extracting and copying cakephp into `/var/www/html/cake_2_5`, when I open to check whether its working in the browser `localhost/cake_2_5`, I am getting this:

```
<?php
/**
* Requests collector.
*
*  This file collects requests if:
*   - no mod_rewrite is available or .htaccess files are not supported
*  - requires App.baseUrl to be uncommented in app/Config/core.php
*   - app/webroot is not set as a document root.
*
* CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
* Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
*
* Licensed under The MIT License
* For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
* Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
*
* @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc.         (http://cakefoundation.org)
* @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
* @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
* @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
*/

/**
*  Get CakePHP's root directory
*/
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);

/**
* This only needs to be changed if the "cake" directory is located
* outside of the distributed structure.
* Full path to the directory containing "cake". Do not add trailing directory separator
*/
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
} 

require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';
```

I changed the permission for `.../app/tmp` file . I am using Ubuntu 14.04 . Actually, at first I got the cakephp page and it was showing *url rewriting is not properly configured on your server*. Then I followed a tutorial in youtube and it's now totally screwed up. Then I reinstalled apache2 and all. But now its always showing like this.

Comment: Your php is not working...

Comment: Yes I checked and my php is not working . How can i make it work . I tried re installing . please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install libapache2-mod-php5 package.